# Change Apache2 ubuntu default page (I can't replace the file!)

Tags: apache

I am new into web page making in ubuntu studio.
I downloaded Apache 2, and when I type localhost in my browser I get the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page, which tells me to replace the index file. But when I try to do it I can't, because there is some sort of permission lock in the var/www/html folder
How do I change this, or how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `index.html` file you need root permissions. Try to run this command from terminal to edit the file:

`sudo gedit /var/www/html/index.html`

That will run the gedit under the root user. You can read more about `sudo` command here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

Comment: I did that, and the gedit opened, but when I try to change the file (change some words) and "save" the file, the terminal writes: (gedit:2541): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: When I refesh the localhost, no changes are made.